# Token Sharing between multiple concurrent requests C#

Tags: c#, security, concurrency, access-token

I have an application (A) where multiple users can login via. username and password and receive a token for upcomning requests. If their token expires they can get a new one. This all works fine. Now the problem is that sometimes App (A) needs to access App (B) via. an API-call that also in itself requires a (separate) token. The call(s) from A to B needs to use the same token regardless of which client makes the call. In other words - app B does not need to know which client makes a call, it just sees every call as coming for app A.

My issue here comes with generating and refreshing TokenB in a threadsafe manner. Let's say TokenB has expired and C1,C2,C3 all makes a call at exactly the same time. Of course only one new token should be generated.

I figure this is a quite common obstacle, but I can't really find any guides on this specific topic of thread-safe token (re)generation.

App A is written in C# btw. Not that it matters for the issue, but perhaps Microsoft has a solution for this.

[image]

Comment: This post is well thought out and specific in its intent. There is no reason to close this as "needs more focus"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question and it is tricky to deal with token refresh in OAuth clients. There are two common techniques. I prefer the second of these since it is more reliable, but it requires trickier code:

- App A refreshes TokenB periodically on a background timer thread, in an effort to prevent 401s
- App A handles 401s, via a token refresh then retrying the request to App B

**SYNCHRONIZING TOKEN REFRESH**

A common technique can be to make the client code look simple from the outside:

```
var data = await myApiClient.getData();
```

But somewhere in the implementation you use a collection of callbacks when a token refresh is necessary. The first of these makes the actual refresh call, and when it completes it resolves all other callbacks with the same result.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

Here is some TypeScript code that handles concurrent in-flight token refresh. In C# you could do an equivalent thing with tasks, and your callback handling would need to be thread safe:

- [API 401 Handling](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts#L59)
- [Token Refresh](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts#L70)
- [Callback Handling](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/utilities/concurrentActionHandler.ts)

Comment: Gary I think that is quite clever, thanks for your input, and examples! 
I am wondering if I can perhaps set a threshold (5 minutes) for token expiration and each time A attempts to call B it will check if the token has less than 5 minutes left. If it does, a new token will be generated (thread safe to avoid multi-creation) and should be used for upcoming calls, but the old token will still be valid for the current client calls. 

This of course requires that multiple parallel tokens are allowed (which it is in B) AND that the current calls finish in less than 5 min (which they always do).

Comment: That's reasonable and a common solution. The only caveat is if a call to App B results in a 401 even though the token is valid and not expired. This can happen in some setups if for example a token signing certificate is renewed or there is a load balancing switch. This may not be relevant in your case, but worth ensuring there are no scenarios where App A cannot recover.

Comment: Hi Gary, alright that sounds like the approach then. Can you elaborate a bit upon how for instance a load balancing switch could result in a 401 for multiple valid tokens? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: In some setups I've seen independent instances of the Authorization Server in US, Europe, Asia Pacific for example. If not relevant then please ignore.

Comment: The reason I thought it was interesting was that I had a colleague calling app B (in a different context, but also using multiple tokens from the same user) and sometimes (very seldom) it gives a 401 for one of the threads even though it is still valid afterwards. That's why I was a bit curious if you had seen any page or article writing about this token 401 "instability". You can perhaps imagine that I was quite surprised you brought that exact issue up as we were banging our heads against the office wall just last week on something very similar! In any case thanks a lot for your help.